# Apply function to data matrix

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a data matrix (a huge one, so I'll create an example), where I want to apply arctan to each element. However, atan() doesn't work on DataMatrix objects.

```
d =bioma.data.DataMatrix(rand(3,4),'Rownames',true,'Colnames','Test');
atan(d);
```

I have two solutions and neither are very good:

- Extract the data, use atan and create a new DataMatrix
- Formulate my own version of atan (with sub-par coding) and use that instead

Any suggestions on how I could solve this in way that is a bit more optimized would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [`dmarrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/dmarrayfundatamatrix.html)

```
d = dmarrayfun( @atan, d );
```

Comment: Shai, the reason I wasn't using dmarrayfun was because without parameters matlab lists it as undefined. As such I assumed it was a feature that had been changed in the latest version.